Align item for various itemize environments
In a beamer, I have a slide with a first long sentence, then two columns : one with a list of item, and the other with a figure.
The first sentence is also present in a itemize environment. The issue is that the bullet triangles are not aligned in the generated file.
Here is a MWE :
\documentclass{beamer}
\usepackage{tikz}
\begin{document}
\begin{frame}
\begin{itemize}
    \item Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit. Quisque maximus placerat nunc, ac aliquet ligula ornare vitae. Nam at diam.
\end{itemize}

\begin{columns}
    \begin{column}{0.5\textwidth}
        \begin{itemize}
            \item Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit.
            \item Morbi sollicitudin dui vitae sagittis bibendum.
            \item Quisque pellentesque lorem nec enim imperdiet, id bibendum tortor finibus.
            \item Quisque sollicitudin libero vel luctus sodales.
        \end{itemize}
    \end{column}

    \begin{column}{0.5\textwidth}
        \centering
        \begin{tikzpicture}
            \draw (0,0) -- (1,1) -- (2,0) -- cycle;
            \draw (1,0) -- (0.5, 0.5) -- (1.5, 0.5) -- cycle;
        \end{tikzpicture}
    \end{column}
\end{columns}

\end{frame}
\end{document}

Resulting in this :

The bullets of the second list are more on the left than the first one. I tried negative hspace, without success.
Is there a way to achieve this ?

Use the onlytextwidth option if you want the same margins for columns and text:
\documentclass{beamer}

\begin{document}
\begin{frame}
\begin{itemize}
    \item Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit. Quisque maximus placerat nunc, ac aliquet ligula ornare vitae. Nam at diam.
\end{itemize}

\begin{columns}[onlytextwidth]
    \begin{column}{0.5\textwidth}
        \begin{itemize}
            \item Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit.
            \item Morbi sollicitudin dui vitae sagittis bibendum.
            \item Quisque pellentesque lorem nec enim imperdiet, id bibendum tortor finibus.
            \item Quisque sollicitudin libero vel luctus sodales.
        \end{itemize}
    \end{column}
    \begin{column}{0.5\textwidth}
        \centering
        \begin{tikzpicture}
            \draw (0,0) -- (1,1) -- (2,0) -- cycle;
            \draw (1,0) -- (0.5, 0.5) -- (1.5, 0.5) -- cycle;
        \end{tikzpicture}
    \end{column}
\end{columns}

\end{frame}
\end{document}



thanks ! that works well !

@Thomas You're welcome!
